# assign multiple variables within apply family

Tags: r, apply

I couldn't thought about a better matching title but I am wondering if something what I am trying below would work in general.

```
l <- list(c(1,2), c(2,3), c(3,4))
sapply(l, function(x,y) x>1 & y>2)
```

So is there a way to assign the two values to two different variables within `*apply` or do I need to access them via `x[1]` and `x[2]`? I have the feeling my solution would reed easier.

Comment: yes you need to do something like `sapply(l, function(i) i[1]>1 & i[2]>2)` or vectorized with do.call, i.e. `do.call(rbind, l)[,1] > 1 & do.call(rbind, l)[,2] > 2`

Comment: `y` is not defined. If you don't need this to be dynamic, you can do `x1 <- x[1]; x2 <- x[2]`. You could automate this, but there's got to be a good reason for doing so.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I was just wondering if something like what I tried exist and I am just not aware of... So might overall be a stupid question, sorry.

Comment: You can also generalize to something like ```sapply(l, `>`, 1:2)``` and then run `colSums` or such. This could save some typing if you want to compare all the values in each entry to some vector. Though you need to beware of recycling in case lengths don't match.

Comment: Yes, use `x[1]`and `x[2]`. Or rearrange `l <- list(1:3, 2:4)` and use `do.call(mapply, c(l, FUN = (function(x, y) x>1 & y>2)))`.